# Getting values from column's cells into string separated by semi-coion

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

Hell guys I have a `datagridview` where I have few columns one of them is `e-mail` and other is `CheckBoxcolumn` named `check` (3rd column). Now I have a string `receivers` and I need to fill this string with all values in which row was the checkbox column checked so I came up with this (working):

```
String prijemci;

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_korespondence.Rows)
        {

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[4].Value) == true)
            {

               receivers = ; // need to fill this string with all values from column "e-mail" separeted by ";" 
            }
        }
```

The datagridview is filled from `SqlServer` via `DataTable` named `dt2` .

So the output would look like: firstmail@provider.com;secondmail@provider.com

Would somebody please help me solve this out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String prijemci;

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_korespondence.Rows)
        {

        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[4].Value) == true)
        {

           receivers += row.Cells["e-mail"].Value.ToString()+";"; // need to fill this string with all values from column "e-mail" separeted by ";" 
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps, unless you want to get the data straight from the `DataTable dt2`

Answer (score 2):

```
receivers = string.Join(";", dtg_korespondence.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                             .Where(r=>Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[4].Value))
                             .Select(r=>r.Cells["e-mail"].Value.ToString()));
```